# Handle Observable.zip response

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to invoke the two service call parallel and populate the response in 
 different object for further processing same as below

```
Observable<O3> o3 = Observable.zip(o1, o2(ent, acct)-> { return new O3(ent,acct);});
```

just want to know, what is the better way to handle the response ?

```
 1 o3.toBlocking().single();
```

---

```
 2) List<O3> O3List;
    O3.subscribe(e -> {
        o3List.add(e);
       });
    O3List.get(0);
```

Comment: Option 1 will block so it is not recommended. Option 2 is not guaranteed to have the `O3List` populated by the time `subscribe` returns. Why not return the `Observable` and keep composing operators on it or let the caller subscribe with the handler for the `O3` value?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like o1 and o2 should actually be Singles (producing exactly one element) and you expect 03 to be one element as well, in which case you can do

```
var result = Single.zip(
    o1.toSingle(), 
    o2.toSingle(),
   (o1Result, o2Result) -> new O3(o1Result, o2Result))
.blockingGet();
```

If you are using Rx java 2.